# Implementing a live wallpaper

Tags: java, android, android-activity, live-wallpaper

I'm making a custom home screen, and I would like to give the user the ability to use live wallpapers in my launcher/home screen. Settings `android:Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar` as my `AppTheme` *kind of* what I want, but not exactly.

There are 2 possible solutions (but please tell me if you can think of another good one);

- Use `android:Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar` as my `AppTheme`

  - Live wallpapers are shown, but the user can't interact with them. It's not great, but I'm fine with this.
- Implement it in the *"proper"* way, so that users can interact with it.

  - The big problem is that I can't find how to do this anywhere. All the documentation I can find tells me how to *create* a live wallpaper, but not how to implement support for it in my custom home screen.

Whichever approach I take, these are 2 problems I'd incur either way and would also like a solution to;

- I need to calculate the "average colour" of the wallpaper (something similar is also fine). How do I do this with a live wallpaper, if at all possible?
- I need to blur the wallpaper at some point. An acceptable solution here is to just overlay it with something that has a black transparent background instead of blurring it, but ideally I'd be able to blur it (even if I could just take kind of a static screenshot of the current state of the live wallpaper so I can blur that). If I *can* get a static snapshot from the current state of the live wallpaper that would also solve my previous problem.

Comment: I have never implemented a meaningful home screen, let alone one with live wallpaper. I'd start by seeing if there are any open source home screen implementations with live wallpaper support. Your request for a static snapshot of the live wallpaper, though, probably is not possible, for security reasons, just as you cannot get a screenshot of any other app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing;

- Set `android:Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar` as the `AppTheme`.
- Disable colour calculation when a live wallpaper is set and default to a transparent black.

  - Use `WallpaperManager.getInstance (this.context).getWallpaperInfo () != null` to detect whether a live wallpaper is set.
- While you *can* get a screenshot of your root view, the area where the live wallpaper is shown will be transparent. So that's no good. I ended up overlaying it with a transparent black overlay so that the white text that is displayed on it is still readable.

Apparently using `android:Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar` does *not* stop the user from interacting with the live wallpaper. The live wallpapers I tested with (the default ones that come with Android) just didn't allow any kind of interaction, which I didn't realise.

I hope this information is able to save someone else some time.